# How a docker container can use another docker container built as an executable and not as a service

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

**Objective:**

Running container "A" that is basically a nodejs server. This server should run an executable such "E" that is expose in another running container.

in simplified code. "A" contains this snippet of code that uses "E".

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

const someArgsForE = {
  arg1:"some_string",
  arg2:123
};

// E is the executable that would be normally run as 'docker run E '{ arg1:"some_string", arg2:123}' ... (ignore the correct escaping)
let childProcess = spawn("E", [JSON.stringify(someArgsForE)]);

childProcess.on('close', (code, signal) => {
  //do whatever with the result... maybe write in a volume
});
```

Ideally "A" can implement some logic so that it can be aware of the existence of "E" .

```
If(serviceExists("E")){ ... do whatever ...}
```

Since also another "E_b" executable might exists and be used by the same server "A" .

I cannot figure out how I can achieve this with **docker-compose** without wrapping "E" and possibly "E_b" into others nodejs services but accessing them as executables.

To have docker inside docker and the using something like

```
let childProcess = spawn("docker", ["run", "E", args]);
```

is not ideal either.

Any clean possible solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is impossible without giving the service unlimited root-level access over the host.  This is not a privilege you usually want to give to processes with network-facing services.

The best approach for what you’re describing is to make the “A” image self-contained by just adding the “E” executable to it.  Depending on what kind of executable it is, you might be able to install it with a package manager or otherwise make it available

```sh
FROM node

# Some things are installable via APT
RUN apt-get update \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
      e-executable

# Or sometimes you have an executable or tarball available locally
ADD f-executable.tar.gz /usr/local

# Routine stuff for a Node app
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json yarn.lock .
RUN yarn install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

The alternative approach is to bind-mount the host’s Docker socket into the container.  As previously mentioned, this gives the service unlimited root-level access over the host.  Common pitfalls to this approach include shell injection attacks that allow a caller to `docker run -v /:/host ...`, filesystem permission problems, and directory mapping issues where the left-hand side of a `docker run -v` option is always a host path even if it’s being launched from a container.  I’d pretty strongly suggest avoiding this path.

Comment: Thanks David, I will look more closely to your proposition I will let you know.

Comment: At the end I opted for wrapping the executable around a very light NodeJS server and build a dedicated image for it. Then through a docker compose file I link the server A to the micro-service that wraps E.